# Python threading : Threads runs twice?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm totally new to python, I was trying threading module when I faced this problem:
-Threads runs twice for some reason, and I have no idea why. I searched everywhere, but didn't manage to find any answer.
Hopefully I can get some help here

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import requests as requests
import threading as threading 


threads = []
i = 0
time.sleep(0.5)
def whatever():
    global i
    while i < 10:
        get = requests.get("http://www.exemple.com")
        print(i)
        i += 1

for t in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=whatever)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

What i want:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

output:

```
0
1
1
3
4
5
6
7
7
9
10
11
12
13
```

Comment: That's not the thread being executed twice, that's concurrency happening.

Comment: How can i fix that?

Comment: If you want things to happen in order, why have threads?

Comment: that's just an example for me to understand the problem, so i can solve it in the real script

Comment: @younesslam If what you want is to control access to `i` from different theads you can use a semaphore, if not, I think your program is doing what you're expecting it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying a global variable from multiple threads is inherently unsafe. You need to lock access to prevent a race condition, like thread A reading `i`, then thread B running and incrementing `i` and storing it back, then thread A coming back in and storing back its incremented copy of `i`, so instead of being incremented twice, it's only incremented once.

The fix is to either lock access, or come up with an innately thread-safe way of doing what you want. On the CPython reference interpreter, you're guaranteed no [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL) releases between bytecodes, so there are tricks to do this without a lock:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

threads = []
igen = iter(range(10))
time.sleep(0.5)
def whatever():
    for i in igen:
        get = requests.get("http://www.exemple.com")
        print(i)

for t in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=whatever)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Using a lock is more complicated, but should be portable to any Python interpreter with predictable(ish, it's still threading after all) behavior:

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Lock

threads = []
i = 0
ilock = Lock()
time.sleep(0.5)
def whatever():
    global i
    while True:
        with ilock:
            if i >= 10:
                break
            icopy = i
            i += 1
        get = requests.get("http://www.exemple.com")
        print(icopy)

for t in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=whatever)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

This won't print out in numerical order, but it will run the requests in parallel, and it will only print out any given value for `i` once.

Comment: May i ask what is time.sleep for ?

Comment: @younesslam: I copied it straight from your code. You're the only one who knows why it's there (it serves no purpose aside from slowing down the program AFAICT).

Comment: Sorry for bothering you,
I'm trying to understand your first code, but what i don't understand is when i get igen(variable) inside function it won't work anymore isn't it the same as keeping it outside function ? Thanks for your help

Comment: @younesslam: It's absolutely not the same. Defining it outside the function means the iterator is shared among all threads, and only one thread gets any given value it generates (your whole problem being producing each `i` value once and only once). If you define it *in* the function, then *every* thread produces *every* value.